Multiple SharePoint List as source for PowerApps cascading picklists
I am working on a form in PowerApps where I have 3 picklists:

Brand1
Brand2
Brand3

I have 3 SharePoint (SP) lists:

Now, in PowerApps, Brand1's picklist should show values from SP list (00_Brand1, column Brand1).
For example, if 'Brand1 Test' is selected in the Brand1 picklist, the values that show in Brand2 picklist should only be 'Brand2TAA' & 'Brand2TBB' (coming from 00_Brand2, column Brand2).
Next, if in the Brand2 picklist, 'Brand2TBB' is selected, then in the Brand3 picklist the values that will show should be 'Brand3XX1' & 'Brand3XX2' (coming from 00_Brand3, column Brand3).
Question:
What is the correct formula in PowerApps to achieve this scenario?
I tried these formula in the Items property of each picklist:
Brand1:
Distinct('00_Brand1',Title)

Brand2:
Filter('00_Brand2', Brand1 code = Brand1.Selected.Value) 

But the result is not great, some Brand1 would show the Brand2s but some does not.
What I am expecting is that the for each Brand1, the corresponding Brand2s will be displayed.


for better efficiency, you can put all the details in one list, it's easier and faster this way.
onstart property of the app, add this list to a collection, that would be even faster than referencing multiple lists everytime input is changes by the user.
ComboBox1 : Distinct(Collection,Title)
ComboBox2 : Distinct(Filter(Collection,Title=ComboBox1.Selected.Value,Column1)
ComboBox3 : Distinct(Filter(Collection,Title=ComboBox1.Selected.Value,Column1=ComboBox2.Selected.Value,Column3)

